# Questions about Security over Using an Ancient Mac Computer on The Internet

Tags: apple, internet, security

I've managed to get my hands on a really old mac computer that was probably built in the late 90's. The operating system was last updated in 2001 to 10.1.4. The problem is that I'm not sure if it's okay to surf the Internet on this machine. There is no anti-virus security for it; and it's not like I can install Norton on it because the computer would be unable to run it since it only has half a gigabyte of RAM. I would think it would at least okay to browse on Google and access most of the pages that Google presents.

Would it be relatively safe for me as long as I use common sense or is it unsafe. If not, is there an anti-virus software that is made for computers like this?

Comment: It would probably make sense to rephrase this question to be less Apple-specific. It’s a quite relevant and interesting subject with regard to old software in general.

Comment: Note that, nonwithstanding any possible security risks, your browsing experience on fairly modern web pages will be, say, a bit disappointing...

Comment: You will most likely find that anything https has expired certificates.

Comment: I have a VirtualBox running 10.11 (Snow Leopard), it gets errors when trying to access most HTTPS websites.

Comment: @user3840170 I think the risk assessment is very specific to the hardware and OS.

Comment: @Barmar I think this risk assessment holds for all non-Windows machines more than 10 or 15 years old. Malware creators aim at targets (OSes, browsers, etc.) with a reasonably large market share.

Comment: @MichaelGraf But do all the old malwares go away? There was virtually no malware for Macs 20 years ago, it's inconceivable that someone would have created something targeting it since. But there was lots of Windows malware 10-15 years ago, and it might still be in the wild, waiting for those machines to run into it.

Comment: There's also the simple fact that there has always been much more malware for Windows than Unix or MacOS. Using a Mac has always been safer, so it changes the risk assessment.

Comment: @Barmar: "But do all the old malwares go away?" Not necessarily all of them, but most of them, by orders of magnitude. For two reasons: People who actively push malware, e.g. through malicious web sites, concentrate on reasonably current OSes. And self-replicating malware is generally caught by virus scanners at most a couple of months after it appears, so has been taken out of circulation long ago. Also note that I wrote "non-Windows machines". The case for, say, a 20-year-old IRIX, BeOS, or OS/2 installation wouldn't be different.

Comment: This might be better on https://security.stackexchange.com/   its not exactly "retro"

Comment: On a Mac, 10.1.4 was a try-it-out release; not until 10.2 or 10.3 was the MacOS X really completely functional.   You'd be better off with an 8.6 install, IMHO.

Comment: @user3840170 Like what others have said, I considered that the risk assessment should be over a particular OS (and hardware). OS's are made differently from each other resulting in some having less vulnerabilities than others. There's also the notion that there is more malware made to target a certain OS than the other. With that being said, I was worried that the question may be too broad if I were to have this over "old software in general" because the main point of most of the answers may likely say something similar to "well that depends," making it harder to get a clear answer.

Comment: Coming to think of it, the "expired certificates" can probably be worked around by setting up a proxy server using a modern OS and telling the Mac and/or browser to use that for access.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Risk assessment is, of course, subjective, but I wouldn't worry too much *if* you're behind a firewall, or a router with NAT and no ports forwarded to this Mac.

In that case, the only danger comes from actions originating at your machine, either done by you or the OS -- which is mostly software you download and run, websites you open, that sort of thing. And most of the malware out there today will not run on that Mac, anyway, either because it's not targeting PowerPC Macs, or because its targeting a browser much more capable than what you'll be able to run on that machine.

As an aside, a late-90s Mac running OS X isn't "really old" ;-)

Comment: "Ancient computer" with 'only' half a gigabyte of RAM. Does this really fit with retro computing? It's not that retro, but browsing without modern JavaScript enabled browser, what possible vector would there be for any remote exploit or virus attack?

Comment: GrantB: Drive-by image decode/display exploits are a risk, especially when using browsers. This specific link describes one for Windows: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Metafile_vulnerability

Comment: When I started dabbling in retrocomputing - around 2002 - the definition seemed to be "more than 10 years old". The time window seems to have lengthened a bit, but I'd say a 20 year old machine is retro enough. Otherwise, where would you draw the line? Regarding JavaScript: JS dates back to 1996, so there should be some level of JS support on a late 90s Mac.

Comment: My loose definition is "retrocomputers don't fit on a desk"  :-)   And yes, I used a desktop VAX in the 1980s, so don't take it too seriously.

Comment: By that standard, the z/OS mainframe at work is retro, and the Apple II is not, so I shan't :-)

Comment: @another-dave I know you were joking, but lots of RC questions are about early PCs and gaming systems.

Comment: Those z/OS things are basically S/360 machines with a tweak here and there, so definitely retro.

Comment: @GrantB To possibly inject some terror into the discussion: If OP were 20 years old, the computer would have been made before they were born. I'd definitely consider anything from before I was born 'retro'

Comment: It seems most of the community would not consider the computer "retro". If I knew, I would've looked at posting this question on a different forum. Also with what @llama mentioned, I am slightly older than 20. So yeah, it's pretty freaking old to me.

Comment: @WolfZwiener, don't worry. I remember discussions in the early 2000s on whether the Amiga was retro; and your questions applies equally to machines most people here *would* consider retro, like, say, a BeBox or a Sun 3/60.